# How to make openconnect app for android makefile?

Tags: android, linux, openconnect

How to build openconnect app from makefile on github?
https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect.git
Am I doing the right thing?

```
cd openconnect/android
make
```

Error output

```
ERROR: Unknown option '--system'. See --help for usage.
make: *** [Makefile:83: /home/openconnect/android/x86_64-linux-android/toolchain/.built] Error 1
```

What to do?